# How to increase chances of my data surviving on hard drive in case computer crashes?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, crash

I have a desktop computer that I use as a "server" for my two other computers. Since it runs 24/7 I would like to increase chances of my data surviving a crash.

I have two physical hard drives. If I store my data on the second hard drive that is not the OS is on then it's a better solution because usually the one with the OS is prone to damages?

Comment: If you care about your data, you should use backup software on a regular schedule.

Comment: Backup like @JSR said.  Then implement mirroring via software or non-parity RAID.  Regular backups first though!  Did anyone say backup?

Comment: Of course I do back up, it's just a thin extra layer of protection

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard any evidence that disks with an OS on them fail more frequently than those without.  Maybe it's true, but that's irrelevant.  Any disk **can** fail.  There are two common ways to manage this risk:  RAID, and regular backups.  They aren't mutually exclusive - you can use one or the other, or both.  If you choose just one approach, backups are a little easier.  You just need any other storage (such as an external drive or a network location with storage), and a scheduled task.  The old maxim is still true:  if your data is important, back it up.

Having said that, separating your data from your OS is still a good idea.  If you do have a failure, of either drive, recovery is easier with as least *some* of your files still intact.

Comment: RAID1 is not a backup. It makes it easier to keep on running if one drive should fail but if your data is encrypted by a cryptolocker virus or you accidentally delete something your copy is also affected. The same goes for damage by fire, power spikes, theft, etc. You should always backup important data, preferably keeping a history and preferably offsite.

Comment: I'm not sure if the above comment was meant as a correction, but I never implied that any kind of RAID is a backup.  It's a protection against disk failure, which is the topic of the question.

Comment: It was not meant as a correction as you indeed answered the question. However, the question and answer could easily be interpreted as being about backups rather than maximizing the chance of continuous operation. Many people still consider RAID to be a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware issues are more common than software issues, so separating the drives by OS and data would still mean you have a 50/50 chance of losing your data when the hard drive crashes.

You could do a RAID 1 array, which essentially clones Disk 1 on to Disk 2, so if either disk fails you can run off of the functioning one while the other is being remade. Other than that, if you're already backing up your data, then the short answer to the original question is not really.

Answer (score 0):

External HHD's are now [as low as ~US$20/TB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HAPGEIE), and there are [free online storage services for data](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/shopping/free-online-storage), as well as [paid cloud storage](https://www.wired.com/story/amazon-just-killed-the-best-deal-in-tech/).

If your system and data are important to you, then you can't rely on backup on the same disk or RAID array.

- A malicious attack could damage, destroy or encrypt the HDD. Since this can occur over a period of time, retained periodic backups are needed to ensure that there is at least one without malware damage.
- A local incident such as fire or flood could destroy the HDD, as well as locally-retained backups, so cloud storage is a useful adjunct.
- The internet may be unavailable or a cloud service may go offline, be held hostage to attack or even go out of business, so cloud storage cannot fully replace local backup.

Consider the cost of losing the system compared to proactive backup.

Answer (score 0):

I layer my approach usually due to budget constraints.

- I almost always split the OS from the the Data; physical hard drives/arrays if possible, but partitions at the least because this can be done on any machine.
- After that, FIRST I make sure I have a solid back first blush up plan.
- Then I focus on robustness of the drive arrays.  Simplest  RAID and definitely non-parity if possible. Linux MD RAID if possible (Not Storage Spaces, ZFS maybe if your tech savy), DRBD is pretty useful too, Enterprise drives for bit error rates
- Then I focus on hardware/infrastructure resiliency/redundancy piece by piece.  Quality UPS, ECC RAM, redundant controllers with drives split across controllers is great [if RAID 1] , redundant power supplies (requires server designed for it usually).
- And finally I try to duplicate and be ready for failover to another machine for catastrohic failure of a fileserver for all the "other" stuff (Bad update/OS crash, machine debilitating elusive hardware errors, etc).  That is have a second machine ready to pickup the load; virtualization helps with this and you have to have file mirrors (duplicate and matching folder structure that is synced somehow).

BUT a rock solid (read overkill) backup "program" could mitigate *almost* ALL problems that arise other than downtime.  Backups includes versioning and saving of deleted files, something RAID and other hardware solutions have NOTHING to do with.